# Problems building Chromium with ninja on Linux

Tags: linux, chromium, ninja

I'm currently trying to build Chromium on Ubuntu 14.10 with Ninja. I've been encountering a few issues so far I've been able to fix, but I've got problems with this one. I'm at the building state.

> > ninja: Entering directory `out/Release' [3/18153] CC
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.float.o FAILED:
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.float.o.d
> >     -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=223108 -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DFLAC__NO_DLL -DFLAC__OVERFLOW_DETECT '-DVERSION="1.2.1"' -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -Igen -I../../third_party/flac/include -I../../third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/include -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal -Xclang -load -Xclang /home/florent/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so
> >     -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-weak-ptr-factory-order -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang strict-virtual-specifiers -momit-leaf-frame-pointer
> >     -mstack-alignment=16 -mstackrealign -fcolor-diagnostics -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-conversion -Wno-format -Wno-unused-result -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -mmmx -m32 -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables   -c ../../third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/float.c -o
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.float.o
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang: 1:
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang: Syntax error:
> >     ")" unexpected [3/18153] CC
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.format.o FAILED:
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.format.o.d
> >     -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=223108 -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DFLAC__NO_DLL -DFLAC__OVERFLOW_DETECT '-DVERSION="1.2.1"' -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -Igen -I../../third_party/flac/include -I../../third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/include -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal -Xclang -load -Xclang /home/florent/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so
> >     -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-weak-ptr-factory-order -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang strict-virtual-specifiers -momit-leaf-frame-pointer
> >     -mstack-alignment=16 -mstackrealign -fcolor-diagnostics -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-conversion -Wno-format -Wno-unused-result -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -mmmx -m32 -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables   -c ../../third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/format.c -o
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.format.o
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang: 1:
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang: Syntax error:
> >     ")" unexpected [3/18153] CC
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.bitmath.o FAILED:
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang -MMD -MF
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.bitmath.o.d
> >     -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DCHROMIUM_BUILD -DCR_CLANG_REVISION=223108 -DCOMPONENT_BUILD -DTOOLKIT_VIEWS=1 -DUI_COMPOSITOR_IMAGE_TRANSPORT -DUSE_AURA=1 -DUSE_ASH=1 -DUSE_PANGO=1 -DUSE_CAIRO=1 -DUSE_DEFAULT_RENDER_THEME=1 -DUSE_LIBJPEG_TURBO=1 -DUSE_X11=1 -DUSE_CLIPBOARD_AURAX11=1 -DENABLE_ONE_CLICK_SIGNIN -DENABLE_PRE_SYNC_BACKUP -DENABLE_REMOTING=1 -DENABLE_WEBRTC=1 -DENABLE_PEPPER_CDMS -DENABLE_CONFIGURATION_POLICY -DENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS -DUSE_UDEV -DDONT_EMBED_BUILD_METADATA -DENABLE_TASK_MANAGER=1 -DENABLE_EXTENSIONS=1 -DENABLE_PLUGINS=1 -DENABLE_SESSION_SERVICE=1 -DENABLE_THEMES=1 -DENABLE_AUTOFILL_DIALOG=1 -DENABLE_BACKGROUND=1 -DENABLE_GOOGLE_NOW=1 -DCLD_VERSION=2 -DENABLE_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_BASIC_PRINTING=1 -DENABLE_PRINT_PREVIEW=1 -DENABLE_SPELLCHECK=1 -DENABLE_CAPTIVE_PORTAL_DETECTION=1 -DENABLE_APP_LIST=1 -DENABLE_SETTINGS_APP=1 -DENABLE_SUPERVISED_USERS=1 -DENABLE_MDNS=1 -DENABLE_SERVICE_DISCOVERY=1 -DV8_USE_EXTERNAL_STARTUP_DATA -DFLAC__NO_DLL -DFLAC__OVERFLOW_DETECT '-DVERSION="1.2.1"' -DUSE_LIBPCI=1 -DUSE_GLIB=1 -DUSE_NSS=1 -DNDEBUG -DNVALGRIND -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=0 -Igen -I../../third_party/flac/include -I../../third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/include -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Werror -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -fvisibility=hidden -pipe -fPIC -Wno-reserved-user-defined-literal -Xclang -load -Xclang /home/florent/src/third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/libFindBadConstructs.so
> >     -Xclang -add-plugin -Xclang find-bad-constructs -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang check-weak-ptr-factory-order -Xclang -plugin-arg-find-bad-constructs -Xclang strict-virtual-specifiers -momit-leaf-frame-pointer
> >     -mstack-alignment=16 -mstackrealign -fcolor-diagnostics -Wheader-hygiene -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wstring-conversion -Wno-c++11-narrowing -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Wno-conversion -Wno-format -Wno-unused-result -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -mmmx -m32 -O2 -fno-ident -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables   -c ../../third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/bitmath.c -o
> >     obj/third_party/flac/src/libFLAC/libflac.bitmath.o
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang: 1:
> >     ../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/bin/clang: Syntax error:
> >     ")" unexpected ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

So sorry that it is so ugly to look at it!

Comment: did you solve this? i am facing same problem

Comment: Maybe it's because of 32-bit architecture on Linux. I see a lot of reports about such compilation errors on Linux 32-bit. It looks like on Linux 64-bit this issue isn't reproducible.